For every $x$ in $(0,\frac\pi2)$, prove using the MVT: $\left( \frac{\sin x}x\right)^3 > \cos x.$
I want to solve this exercise :

For every $x$ in $(0,\frac\pi2)$, prove using the mean value theorem that
$$ \left( \frac{\sin x}x\right)^3 > \cos x.$$

Here is what I have done :
Applied the mean value theorem on $\sin x$:
$$ 
\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{\sin x- \sin0}{x - 0} = \sin'c= \cos c\quad \text{for } c \in(0, x).
$$
So, the inequality becomes:
$$ \cos^3c>\cos x.
$$
But I don't know how to continue. Can you give a tip?

I can't read your handwriting at all. Why not just write it in MathJax?

@SeanRoberson Sorry,i did write now on mathJax

This question is similar to: Verify $\cos{x}<\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\right)^3$ for $0<x<\pi/2$.. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RezaRajaei thank you
